# Remove animation at the end of the loop count

Tags: loops, animation, sdk, lua, coronasdk

I'm using the following code to play explosion animation, How can I removeSelf the animation when it finished the loop-count?

```
        function showExplotion(event) 
            local sheetData = { width=32, height=32, numFrames=13, sheetContentWidth=128, sheetContentHeight=128 }
            local mySheet = graphics.newImageSheet( "media/fire.png", sheetData )
              local sequenceData = {
                --{ name = "normalRun", start=1, count=13, loopCount = 1, time=800 }
                { name = "fastRun", frames={ 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 }, time=800, loopCount = 1 }
            }

            local animation = display.newSprite( mySheet, sequenceData )
            animation.x = event.x
            animation.y = event.y
            animation:play()
        end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add listener to your sprite animation to detect it's phase

```
function showExplotion(event) 


        local sheetData = { width=32, height=32, numFrames=13, sheetContentWidth=128, sheetContentHeight=128 }
        local mySheet = graphics.newImageSheet( "media/fire.png", sheetData )
        local sequenceData = {
            --{ name = "normalRun", start=1, count=13, loopCount = 1, time=800 }
            { name = "fastRun", frames={ 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 }, time=800, loopCount = 1 }
        }

        local animation = display.newSprite( mySheet, sequenceData )
        animation.x = event.x
        animation.y = event.y
        animation:play()

       local function mySpriteListener( event )

         if ( event.phase == "ended" ) then
              animation:removeSelf()
              animation = nil
         end
      end

       animation:addEventListener( "sprite", mySpriteListener )  

  end
```

Comment: Thanks. *animation = nil not ==nil